# Is it any option to disable auto generate provisioning profile from Xcode 5.0.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

- I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and developing ios 7 Application with Push notification service.When I try to create a Push Notification service enabled Provisioning Profile in Dev center,I have seen lot of Provisioning profiles created with message as **"ios Team Development provisioning profile(Managed by Xcode)"**.
- I want to develop my application using my Push notification enabled provisioning profile only. But I didn't get any option to select this particular provisioning profile.In build settings, I able to select only my Apple ID only. If I select this it selects "ios Team Development provisioning profile(Managed by Xcode)" only not my push enabled provisioning profile. Is it any option to disable auto generate provisioning profile from Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

As to me, I simply choose 'Team' of my Apple ID in 'General' tab, and everything is done if proper APNS certificates are set in dev center, because Xcode 5 is really smart.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, earlier versions of Xcode used to let you select your provisioning profile in the build settings under Code Signing Identity. Now you select your provisioning profile under a separate build setting called Provisioning Profile, and once that is selected, you can select your developer certificate under Code Signing Identity. This part is more intuitive than the old way, if you know the new setting is there.

If your desired provisioning profile isn't available under the Provisioning Profile build setting, then you have to go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > [account name] > View Details and click the Refresh button under the Provisioning Profiles list. That should download your current profiles so you can select them in the build settings. This part is totally unintuitive and hidden. But one thing is for sure ... after you've done it enough times that it becomes intuitive, Apple will change it again!